# Elixir sourcemaps wrong file app.css[sm] bug

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, source-maps, laravel-elixir

With elixir, I compile my stylus files. But I have a problem with generating sourcemaps. In the chrome console, it gives me the right information for the basic files (eg, for reset css). But afterwards, it put me all styles in my app.css file generated.

Besides, he puts me [sm] next and I do not know what that means.

My gulpfile :

```
elixir(function (mix) {

mix.tinypng({
    key: '###',
    sigFile: '.tinypng-sigs',
    summarize: true,
});

mix.copy('resources/assets/img/*.*', 'public/img/');
mix.copy('resources/assets/svg-inline/*.*', 'public/svg/');
mix.copy('resources/assets/fonts/*.*', 'public/fonts/');

mix.stylus('app.styl'), {
    use: [autoprefixer('last 7 versions', 'ie8' )]
};

mix.scriptsIn();

mix.browserSync({
    proxy: 'ecoleinfographie.app'
});
```

})

Here is a picture of the problem :
[[image: app.css[sm] Is not normal[1]]

Comment: I believe you have the wrong elixir selected. You currently have this tagged with the Elixir programming language. Is this what you are using, or are using laravel-elixir?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use elixir with Laravel. I do not understand what you're saying. I imported laravel-elixir to the top of my gulpfile. It works well, it's just the sourcemaps that are not going properly.

Comment: I am talking about the how you tagged this question.